# D3 get axis values on zoom event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple zoomable chart from [d3 zoomable area](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254)
[image]

It has date x-axis, when user zooms, i want to get chart x-axis bound values. 
For example i zoomed like this,
[image]

I would like to get x-axis values, 23-May-2015 and 31-May-2015 for my internal needs, is possible? Tried this but no success

```
function draw(){
            var e = d3.event;
            if(e){
                var tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[0], width - width*e.scale));
                var ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[1], height - height*e.scale));
                console.log(x.invert(e.translate[0]), x.invert(tx));
                zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
                g.attr('transform', [
                    'translate(' + [tx, ty] + ')',
                    'scale(' + e.scale + ')'
                ].join(' '));
                svg.call(zoom);
            }
            svg.select('g.x.axis').call(xAxis);
            svg.select('g.y.axis').call(yAxis);
            svg.select('path.area').attr('d', area);
            svg.select('path.line').attr('d', line_low);
            svg.select('path.line').attr('fill', 'blue').attr('stroke-width', 4).attr('d', minTempLimitLine);
            svg.select('path.line').attr('fill', 'red').attr('stroke-width', 4).attr('d', maxTempLimitLine);
        }
```

But `x.invert(e.translate[0])` constantly returns `Sat Oct 04 2014 12:56:40 GMT+0600 (ALMT)` which is first date in my data (filtered by date), also i don't think it's related to `e.translate` as it has only 2 values, for x, y.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a working snippet? We need to see how you register the listener for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254):

Then in the *draw()* function

`x.domain()`

will give you the max/min array for x-axis, of the current state.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from your xAxis scale function.

```
xScale.domain()[0];
xScale.domain()[1];
```