# d3.js get new domain values after rescale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rescale

I try to get the new axes values after rescaling my axes.

I tried to get them from `y.domain()` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947846/d3-get-axis-values-on-zoom-event) but the values returned are the initial values.

So what am i doing wrong here?

Relevant code:

```
function zoomed() {

  for(let i = 0; i < ys.length; i++){
    yAxes[i].call(
      d3.axisLeft(ys[i])
        .scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(ys[i]))
    )
  }

  //Now I need the new values

  console.log(ys[0].domain()) //returns [0, 10] which are my initial domain values for this axis.

}
```

After zooming, the values i have on screen are bigger than 0 and smaller than 10.
So how do i get my domains new min and max values?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rzxa19kq/51/) is a fiddle with an older version of my code, which has the exact same behavior (see `zoomed()` function).

Maybe I misunderstand what the domain is and how it works, what I need are the new max and min values of my axis.

Comment: could you post a fiddle or a codepen of what youve got so far

Comment: Added fiddle to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basing my answer on this code from the fiddle:

```
  function zoomed() {
    let center = getBoundingBoxCenterX(rect);
    let chartsWidth = (2 * center) * d3.event.transform.k;
    d3.event.transform.x = center - chartsWidth / 2;
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x).scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
    yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));
    zAxis.call(d3.axisRight(z).scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(z)));

    //here i need the new values
    console.log(y.domain()) //returns [0,6]
```

*Edit*

You can get the axis scale this way:

```
let leftAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y));
console.log('new domain values', leftAxis.scale().domain())
```

I've got a version of the fiddle with this working: https://jsfiddle.net/aj5sLz5u/